# Pass a reference to a cell as the default value for an optional parameter while creating a custom function

Tags: excel, vba, default-value, optional-parameters

I am trying to write a custom function where one of the parameters is an optional parameter that I want to default to the value I have stored in the cell B2 is nothing is entered by the user. Is this possible?

An example of the code I wrote is:

```
Function PleaseWork(First_Date As Date, Optional Second_Date as Variant = Worksheets"(MM_CALC").Range("B2").Value)

PleaseWork = First_Date - Second_Date

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make the default value something that needs to be evaluated.

Instead, check to see if it's missing, and set it then.

```
Function PleaseWork(First_Date As Date, Optional Second_Date As Variant) As Variant
  ' check if it is supplied as an argument
  If IsMissing(Second_Date) Then
    Second_Date = Worksheets("MM_CALC").Range("B2").Value
  End If
  ' make sure it's a date first
  If IsDate(Second_Date) Then
      PleaseWork = First_Date - CVDate(Second_Date)
  Else
      Debug.Print "Error: '" & Second_Date & "' is not a date."
      PleaseWork = "Error"
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: :) Please remember to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer so the question does not remain open.